# Marshalling safearray of saferay from VARIANT c++ to c#

Tags: c#, c++, native, marshal

Пытаюсь вызвать функцию в .net из нативной библиотеки следующего вида:

```
typedef int (WINAPI* TGetAllObjects)(int hModel, VARIANT& objects);
```

Если вызывать её в c++ клиенте, дебаггер показывает, что objects - это safearray of VARIANT. А каждый VARIANT этого массива - это safearray of BSTR.

Я пытался реализовать следующим образом на C#:

```
public delegate TRetCode TGetAllObjects(int hModel, 
    [Out,In,MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_VARIANT )] ref MyStruct[] objects);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_BSTR)]
    public string[] Objects;
}
```

при вызове метода выдаёт ошибку:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeArrayTypeMismatchException: "Specified array was not of the expected type."

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно организовать маршаллинг данных в такой ситуации.

Comment: Из C# можно вызывать только С функции.

Comment: @user7860670 В данном случае вызываемая функция вполне соответствует экспортированной С функции __stdcall, хоть и была написана на Delphi. Остальные функции этой же нативной библиотеки, где параметры попроще, отлично работают в c#)

Comment: Зачем вы в двух местах пишете `MarshalAs`? Зачем `LayoutKind.Sequential` для структуры, состоящей из одного поля? Что именно предствляет собой VARIANT? в заголовочном файле наверное есть сигнатура?

Comment: @aepot это просто попытки подобрать решение, исходя из найденных примеров. VARIANT - это вот эта вот структура:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-variant?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DRU-RU%26k%3Dk(OAIDL%252FVARIANT);k(VARIANT);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(DevLang-C%252B%252B);k(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue

Comment: То что вы описали = safearray of safearray of BSTR, то есть массив массивов строк, а не массив строк. Где BSTR - `typedef OLECHAR* BSTR`. Итого, быть может это `string[][]`? [Вот здесь](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3004/The-Complete-Guide-to-C-Strings-Part-II-String-Wra) можно почитать и понять, что там внутри на самом деле.

Comment: @aepot Я пробовал использовать string[][] - выдало исключение, что двумерные массивы не поддерживаются при маршаллинге)

Comment: Я не знаю, как может смаршалиться сложная струткра, вам надо по сути реаоизовать в C# структуру, аналогичную tagVARIANT, где union заменить на нужный тип, например `string[] Objects`. Можете указать `LayoutKind.Explicit` и добавить отступ перед массивом строк нужное кличество байт. Просто сейчас он у вас по адресу 0, а должен быть минимум 8, не  знаю, сколько там байт занимает VARTYPE, но точно не меньше 2.

Comment: `SafeArrayTypeMismatchException` - какой из двух маршраллеров вам дает это исключение?

Comment: @aepot тот, что в делегате определён.

Comment: ой, а почему `delegate` а не `[DllImport] extern`? Вы же сами говорите, что это `stdcall`.

Comment: @aepot да я обычно реализовываю через loadlibrary и GetProcAddress на случай, если выгружать библиотеку потом через FreeLibrary. Переписал через DllImport - все также пока

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ нашёлся:
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66011800/marshalling-safearray-of-safearray-from-variant-in-c-to-c-sharp):

```
delegate int TGetAllObjects(int hModel, ref object objects);
```

И в качестве objects отправить туда подобный массив массивов:

```
  object objects = new object[] { new string[] { "A", "B" }, new string[] { "C", "D" } };
```

Затем, кастим objects до object[]. А чтобы получить внутренние массивы кастим их к Array. Напрямую к string[] каст не работает.

В итоге клиентский код выглядит так:

```
object objects = new object[] { new string[] { "A", "B" }, new string[] { "C", "D" } };

rc = getAllObjects(hModel, ref objects);

var strings = Array.ConvertAll((object[]) objects, o => ((Array)o).Cast<string>().ToList());
```

Всем спасибо за помощь.

Comment: `foreach (string elem in array) result.Add(elem);`, еще не злоупотребляйте `as` там, где получить `null` - плохо, может потом вылезти очень неудобный `NullReferenceException`. Лучше делайте так  `var array = (Array)nativeArray`, так как `InvalidCastException` намного проще отлаживать. Делайте `as` только там, где `null` - нормально, или там где у вас есть значение по умолчанию, например `var array = nativeArray as Array ?? Array.Empty<string>()`, или надо бросить какое-то своё исключение после `??`.

Comment: Кстати, не проще ли будет заменить весь этот метод на одну строчку `var strings = Array.ConvertAll((object[])objects, o => ((string[])o).ToList());`? Или даже без списков `string[][] strings = Array.ConvertAll((object[])objects, o => (string[])o);`

Comment: @aepot Спасибо, поправил. В моём случае это не работает. Каст к string[ ] вызывает System.InvalidCastException: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[*]' to type 'System.String[]'." Связано это скорее всего с тем, что в дельфи индексация массивов начинается с 1)

Comment: Вероятно так и есть, но попытаться стоило. :) foreach поправить тоже не прокатило?

Comment: @aepot Прокатило) Я и не обратил внимание сначала) В итоге сократил еще через Cast. Не думал, что этот метод расширения работает на голом Array)

Comment: Ну тогда прокатит и `o => ((Array)o).Cast<string>().ToList()`. `Array` реализует `IEnumerable`, а следовательно на нем работают и Linq расширения и `foreach`.